# 3 dimension GiS data with django and postgis

Tags: 3d, postgis, geodjango

I could use a third dimension in my current project, which strongly involves google-maps and django.  How do I deal with this?

```
class Waypoint(models.Model):
    latlng = models.PointField()

>>> p = Point( 5, 10, 20)
<Point object at Ox...>
>>> p.kml
'<Point><coordinates>5.0,10.0,20.0</coordinates></Point>'
>>> w = Waypoint.objects.all()[0]
<Waypoint: Waypoint object>
>>> w.latlng = p
>>> w.latlng.kml
'<Point><coordinates>5.0,10.0,20.0</coordinates></Point>'
>>> w.save()
>>> w = Waypoint.objects.all()[0]
<Waypoint: Waypoint object>
>>> w.latlng.kml
'<Point><coordinates>5.0,10.0,0</coordinates></Point>'
                              ^
```

Note third diemsnion is ignored.   GRRR!